# vscode how to remove vscode.workspace.onDidChangeTextDocument listener?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I added a listener with `vscode.workspace.onDidChangeTextDocument` . How do I remove this listener when I am no longer in need of it? Or do I have to keep some state internal to the extension to ignore the event when the callback fires?

Comment: See https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#events